# Do I need to register as a Money Service Business for a cryptocurrency trading platform?

Tags: united-states, currency, irs, cryptocurrency, money-service

According to the U.S. Department of Treasury FinCen: [Money Service Business Definition](https://www.fincen.gov/money-services-business-definition). The term "money services business" includes;

> any person doing business, whether or not on a regular basis or as an
>   organized business concern, in one or more of the following
>   capacities:
>
> 1. **Currency dealer or exchanger**.
> 2. Check casher.
> 3. Issuer of traveler's checks, money orders or stored value.
> 4. Seller or redeemer of traveler's checks, money orders or stored value.
> 5. **Money transmitter**.
> 6. U.S. Postal Service.

According to the IRS's [Virtual Currency Guidance](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/irs-virtual-currency-guidance), and in more [detail](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-14-21.pdf),

> For federal tax purposes, virtual currency is treated as property.
>   General tax principles applicable to property transactions apply to
>   transactions using virtual currency.

The way I understand this is, You don't fall under any capacities as a "Money Service Business" if;

- Cryptocurrency is to be treated as property, NOT CURRENCY OR MONEY.
- Don't allow exchanging from cryptocurrency to fiat.
- Don't allow exchanging from fiat to cryptocurrency.
- Only allow Cryptocurrency-to-Cryptocurrency exchanges.

Is this correct?

If not, please explain why using the previously mentioned guidelines/documents or any other document or statement issued in an official capacity by a U.S. agency stating why this is incorrect.